# Setting Navigation url to hyperlink dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to set navigation url to a hyperlink which is inside a gridview.

Im creating the table inside the gridview using a literal in backend c# code.

The code now look like inside GridviewRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

```
Literal.Text += "<asp:HyperLink ID='hlContact' runat='server' NavigateUrl='#'>Contact </asp:HyperLink>";
```

I want to set the navidation inside this code

If anyone have an idea it will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: This will just render the text "<asp:HyperLink..." on your page, not actually create a control and add it to viewstate. Bummer, but this approach will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we writing `html` content to the `literal`, it won't picking up the `asp hyperlink` correctly. But when I used the  normal `“a”` tag, it taking the redirection path correctly.

```
literal.Text += "a ID='linkcontact' runat='server' href='" + "www.website./pagename.aspx?ID=" + id + "'>contact</a>";
```

Answer (score 5):

You should just create a HyperLink control, instead of trying to add one to a literal:

```
HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
lnk.Text = "Hello World!";
lnk.NavigateUrl = "~/somefolder/somepage.aspx";

e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(lnk);
```

If your approach can work, you could try something like this:

```
Literal.Text += String.Format("<asp:HyperLink ID=\"hlContact\" runat=\"server\" NavigateUrl=\"{0}\">Contact</asp:HyperLink>", navigationUrl);
```

If you want to use a Literal control though, I would do something like this instead:

```
Literal.Text += String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">Contact</a>", navigationUrl);
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question or context, but won't that simply render "<asp:Hyperlink..." to the response being sent back to the browser?  At what point will the aspx page "re-process" the literal's text so that "<asp:Hyperlink..." is rendered as "<a href=..."?

Comment: @mikemanne: That was my thought as well, hence my first suggestion to add a HyperLink control to a parent container of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to simply databind a HyperLink field in a GridView with a bound field, you can use a TemplateField. Here is an example to do it up front and not the hassle of adding it in the code behind.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact" SortExpression="LastName, FirstName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Page.aspx?ID={0}", Eval("CustID").ToString()) %>'>Contact</asp:HyperLink>)
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

for make a menu and submenu code c#. with variables and navigateurl is of  form next

```
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>                      
                    <asp:MenuItem>
                       <asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
                       <asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>

                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>

    NavigationMenu.Items[0].Text = "xxxxxx"; name of menu
    MenuItem menu = NavigationMenu.Items[0];
    MenuItem submenu = new MenuItem("xxxxxx"); //name of submenu
    submenu.NavigateUrl = "~/Main/xxxxx.aspx?id=" + id + "";

    MenuItem submenu1 = new MenuItem("xxxxxxx");//name of sumbenu1
    submenu1.NavigateUrl = "~/Main/xxxxxxx.aspx?id=" + id + "";

    menu.ChildItems.Add(submenu);
    menu.ChildItems.Add(submenu1);
```

Comment: Seems you went on a different direction! This is not about creating a menu with navigation. This is a link + some other information inside a `grid-view` column where data been appended to a `literal`. Seems you joined the site today. Appreciate your contribution. But have a look at the questions where there aren’t any accepted answers. If answer is accepted you will see a check mark on left to the answer!